# How can I upload multiple files into Magnolia CMS assets app from a custom form

Tags: javascript, java, rest, magnolia

**Short version**

I have a webapp using Magnolia, I need to upload a comment with posibility of multiple files, I want to use AJAX, before saving the files as assets I want to be able to check the user's permission, I figured I need a custom Java-based REST endpoint, I made it work, but I have issues saving "jcr:data" into an asset.

**Long version**

I have a webapp, I have registered users (using PUR), I have different roles for users (for simplicity let's say *User* and *Editor*) and I have a *Post* and a *Comment* content types. Every *User* can create a *Post* and add files, every *Post* holds the creator's UUID, array of *Comment* UUIDs and array of file UUIDs (from Assets app), every *Post* has a comment section and every *Comment* can have files attached (zero or multiple) to it. Every *Editor* can post a comment to every *Post*, but *Users* can only post comments to their own *Posts*.

My form for comments looks something like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="comment-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple />
  <textarea name="text"></textarea>
  <button type="button" onclick="sendComment();">Send</button>
</form>
```

I tried using Javascript model to process the data and I was able to save the asset correctly, however only one. I couldn't access the other files in the model.

I tried solving it (and improving user experience) by using AJAX and a REST endpoint. I opted not to use the Nodes endpoint API, because I didn't know how to solve the permission issue. I know I can restrict access to REST for each role, but not based on ownership of the *Post*. So I created my own Java-based endpoint (copied from documentation).

In the **sendComment()** function in Javascript I create an object with properties like name, extension,  mimeType, ..., and data. I read in the documentation that you should send the data using the Base64 format, so I used **FileReader()** to accomplish that:

```
var fileObject = {
  // properties like name, extension, mimeType, ...
}

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   // this part is easy
};
xhttp.open("PUT", "http://localhost:8080/myApp/.rest/assets/v1/saveAsset", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
  fileObject.data = reader.result;
  // I also tried without the 'data:image/png;base64,' part by reader.result.split(",")[1];
  xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(fileObject));
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);  //where file is the value of the input element.files[i]
```

In Java I created a POJO class that has the same properties as the javascript object. Including a **String data**.

The code for the endpoint looks like this:

```
public Response saveAsset(Asset file) {
  // Asset is my custom POJO class
  Session damSession;
  Node asset;
  Node resource;

  try {
    damSession = MgnlContext.getJCRSession("dam");
    asset = damSession.getRootNode().addNode(file.getName(), "mgnl:asset");

    asset.setProperty("name", file.getName());
    asset.setProperty("type", file.getExtension());
    resource = asset.addNode("jcr:content", "mgnl:resource");

    InputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getData().getBytes());
    ValueFactory vf = damSession.getValueFactory();
    Binary dataBinary = vf.createBinary(dataStream);

    resource.setProperty("jcr:data", dataBinary);
    resource.setProperty("fileName", file.getName());
    resource.setProperty("extension", file.getExtension());
    resource.setProperty("size", file.getSize());
    resource.setProperty("jcr:mimeType", file.getMimeType());

    damSession.save();

    return Response.ok(LinkUtil.createLink(asset)).build();
  } catch (RepositoryException e) {
    return Response.ok(e.getMessage()).build(); //I know it's not ok, but that's not important at the moment
  }
}
```

The asset gets created, the properties get saved apart from the **jcr:data**. If I upload an image and then download it either by the link I get as a response or directly from the Assets app, it cannot be opened, I get the format is not supported message. The size is 0, image doesn't show in the Assets app, seems like the data is simply not there, or it's in the wrong format.

How can I send the file or the file data to the Java endpoint? And how should I receive it? Does anybody know what am I missing? I honestly don't know what else to do with it.

Thank you

Comment: Code looks ok. Are you sure you have received the file data? What’s the size of array you are trying to save?

Comment: @Jan I tested it by returning the data back from the endpoint and displaying the image in the img tag and it displayed correctly, so I assume it is recieved correctly.
What do you mean by the array? I was testing it with only 1 file (428 kB).

Comment: I meant the byte array that you pass into binary: `file.getData().getBytes()`. As I said before all the code looks ok, so not sure where the issue is. You said, all other properties are saved correctly, is the value of "size" matching the full size of your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input stream had to be decoded from Base64.

```
InputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64(file.getData().getBytes()));
```

...and it only took me less than 3 months.

Noticed it after going through the source code for REST module that for unmarshalling Binary Value it had to be encoded to Base64, so I tried decoding it and it started to work.